# Hibernate Query Error Mysql

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate query.
My database is MySql.

When we run i got error like

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.reportError - line 1:293: unexpected token: MINUTE

My query is follows below

```
select distinct lol.spajNo,wasup.key11,lol.creationDate  from facebook lol , watsapp wasup where " +
            "lol.spajNo=wasup.key21 and  lol.creationDate >= DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL -"+timeRange+" MINUTE) and " +
                    "lol.status not in ?1 and lol.retryAttempt > "+NO_RETRY_ATTEMPT;
```

Comment: check the query condition DATE_ADD(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL -"+timeRange+" MINUTE)  and not in ?1 ;

Answer (score 0):

Afaik `INTERVAL` is not supported by hql, so you either change the query, switch to native query or pass the value as query parameter